# When typing ^ i have to type twice to get that symbol in Xfce

Tags: xfce, dead-keys

I use Debian testing with XFCE as desktop environment.

I have a german keyboard and sometimes use `^` (circumflex). When I hit that key once, the symbol is shown with an underscore. I have to hit it again to get rid of that underscore.

I assume this is to get symbols like `⁴` etc., but I don't want that functionality, I never use it. But I don't know where I can turn it off.

Can anyone tell me how to turn that off in xfce? At the moment I hit that key four times to show `^^` but that's annoying!

edit: as requested:

```
oli@DESKTOP-SJIB21T:~$ locale
LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

The keyboard model in use is "Generic PC-Keyboard with 105 keys" and the layout was "use system settings". Now it is "Deutsch (ohne Akzenttasten)", with those settings it works.

Comment: Doubt I can help directly, but more info might help others help you. What's the make and model of your keyboard and what settings do you have selected for **Keyboard model** and **Keyboard layout** on the Layout tab of the Xfce Keyboard dialog?

Comment: i guess the model doesnt matter, but its a microsoft sidewinder x4. xfce uses the system defaults - i dont know what those are. my locale is set to de_DE.utf8. I once found where this can be disabled but... i can't find it anymore. it was somewhere in the xfce settings.

Comment: If you switch off **Use system defaults** on Xfce Keyboard dialog's Layout tab, you can select from many keyboard models and add other keyboard layouts. My system has 27 different layouts listed under three German layout groups. Unfortunately, though, I have no keyboard model listing for the microsoft sidewinder x4.

Comment: Disable whatever IME/"Input method" you have active. I don't remember if the stock Xfce has this setting anywhere, might just need to look at the autorun applications and disable anything that looks like one (Fcitx, etc).

Comment: this has nothing to do with the layout of the keyboard, i guess all german keyboards have this key and its fine that this key exists. its the double-functionality that is included in xfce that annoys me. i will anyway switch off "use system defaults" and select "generic 105 keys keyboard", but i'm afraid that wont change anything.
edit: oh i was wrong, i use now "german, without akzent" and seems to work! thanks @DavidYockey

Comment: It has nothing to do with the physical layout of the keyboard, but everything to do with the keyboard layout used by the OS, that's usually where dead keys are implemented. For Finnish, there's often one layout called "Finnish (no dead keys)", or such. If you found a similar one for German too, you should probably post that as an answer.

Comment: Please add all the extra information to your question, it gets lost in comments. We particularly need the output of `locale` as well as the exact name of the keyboard layout you have selected in your XFCE settings. As others have said, this is likely related to the chosen layout and especially to "dead keys".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing that your keyboard's a SideWinder X4, you may want to take a look at the Sidewinder daemon at https://github.com/tolga9009/sidewinderd. It's intended to provide "Linux support for Microsoft SideWinder X4 / X6 and Logitech G103 / G105 / G710+." Don't know if it'll solve the problem, but it's something to consider.

edit by J.Doe: indeed it worked to disable "use global settings" in the keyboard dialog, and then change the layout from "german" to "german (ohne akzenttaste)" (as suggested in a comment to the original question)

Comment: I can't imagine the physical layout would be relevant here. This sort of thing is usually caused by the chosen layout at the software level, most likely one with dead keys.